# Difficulty installing and compiling Dada Engine on OSX

Tags: software-installation, make

I am trying to install Dada Engine. The readme can be found here:

https://github.com/orenmazor/Dada-Engine

I have run the install bash successfully and "sudo make". However, when I run "make install" as per the readme instructions, I get the following line:

> /bin/sh mkdirs.sh /usr/local/bin
>
> /bin/sh: mkdirs.sh: No such file or directory
>
> make: *** [/usr/local/bin] Error 127

Any advice on how to properly compile this program would be helpful.

Comment: Wish I could help.  I've been trying for years.  There's a 1.03 release out there also (I don't know if this is it) which might help, but while I get it to compile, it doesn't work.

Your OS X system might not have a directory called "/usr/local/bin" -- it's assumed to exist on UNIX systems but doesn't always on Mac.